# Why can "a mod n and a mod m" be simplified to "a mod n*m"?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

In the classic FizzBuzz programming problem the programmer is tasked with either printing out "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz", or $n$, for $0 \le n \le k$  for some $k$, depending on whether $n$ is divisible by 3, 5, both 3 and 5, or neither. Here an example output for $0 \le n \le 10$:

```
FizzBuzz           0 mod 15 = 0
1                
2
Fizz               3 % 3 = 0
4
Buzz               5 % 5 = 0
Fizz               6 % 3 = 0
7
8
Fizz               9 % 3 = 0
Buzz               10 % 5 = 0
```

One common solution is to just check if each condition satisfies one of the following equations and to react accordingly:
 - $ n\mod5 = 0$ and $n\mod 3 = 0$
 - $ n\mod5 = 0$
 - $ n\mod3 = 0$

But sometimes people replace the first condition with $n \mod 15 = 0$.

So I guess my real question is, why are these two conditions interchangeable? Obviously this solution just multiplies $3$ and $5$, but why are we allowed to do that?

Comment: Look up the "Chinese Remainder Theorem".

Comment: I don't have a strong mathematics background, but I attempted to read the theorem statement on its wikipedia page. Does this mean that the only reason it works in this case is because 3 and 5 are prime numbers?

Comment: @Dylan No, but almost. It's because they're _coprime_:  They do not have any prime factors in common. It works just as well with $14$ and $33$, but not with $12$ and $18$.

Comment: I see. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're allowed to do this only if the moduli in question are coprime numbers. This has been proved by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

If you're interested on why it doesn't work for numbers which aren't coprime, you can make use of the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Group, which tells us that $\mathbb{Z}_{pq} \cong  \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_q$, iff $(p,q) = 1$

Comment: The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups _is_ the Chinese remainder theorem (and chances are, abelian groups is a completely foreign concept to the OP, so even if it _did_ actually explain anything, it wouldn't help). It is not an explanation, it's just a rewriting. Instead, if you want to explain why it doesn't work when the numbers aren't coprime, you should explain a counterexample in depth.

Comment: @Arthur You can say so, although I would argue that the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups is a better version (generalization) of the CRT.

Comment: That is true. It is a classification of all finite abelian groups, instead of just the pure modular arithmetic ones, and it handles non-coprime cases. So on that account, you are right. Apart from that small correction, though, I still stand by my comment.

Answer (score 1):

n mod 3 = 0 $\implies n = 3k$ for some $k \in{\mathbb{Z}}$ and similarily, n mod 5 = 0 $\implies n = 5z$ for some $z \in{\mathbb{Z}}$, so $n = 3\cdot 5 \cdot x$ for some $x \in{\mathbb{Z}}$ which is equivalent to n mod 15 = 0

Comment: You should be more careful, as concluding that $n= 3 \cdot 5 \cdot x$ relies on the fact $(3,5) = 1$, which you haven't mentioned

Comment: True. I guess i should mention it. I assumed that since 3 and 5 are prime factors of n, it would follow that 3*5 divides n also.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this explanation. Mostly because, one counterexample to this line of reasoning is $12039810982 \mod 1459 = 0$, $12039810982 \mod 2918 = 0$, however $12039810982 \mod (1459\cdot2918) = 4248608$. Can you explain why your example would hold up but not mine? Thank you!

Comment: 2918 is not prime in your example

Comment: Ah okay, I was just wondering if you were using a different method to find your answer because you didn't mention the restriction of the divisors needing to be prime and the other answers/comments did.

Comment: @Dylan The reason why it doesn't work in your case is because $1459$ and $2918$ aren't coprime numbers. In fact $2918 = 2 \cdot 1459$

Comment: Not necessarily prime, but as others have said, coprime, which is essentially "prime relative to each other"

Comment: Right, sorry. I messed up the phrasing of that sentence. Thank you both! This has been a great discussion.